# Скрипт не запускает браузер при загрузке системы

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

Есть `bash` скрипт на `raspberry pi`, который должен запускать окно браузера и скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
chromium-browser --start-fullscreen <url> &
python3 /home/pi/main.py &
```

У него стоят права на выполнение. Если запускать его просто в системе, то все работает, открывается окно браузера и запускается `python` скрипт. Я добавил этот файл в `rc.local`. Но при запуске системы запускается только `python` скрипт, а браузер - нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: было бы очень странно, если бы браузер (или что угодно другое, требующее соединения с x-сервером) запустился. // вам нужен т.н. «kiosk mode». инструкций в интернетах — вагон и маленькая тележка. а здесь я подходящего ответа, увы, не нашёл (хотя идентичные вопросы уже неоднократно задавались).

Comment: Автологин в пользователя и правильно прописанный *.xinitrc*. Без systemd делов на пять минут, но да, я из старой школы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему именно этого скрипта я не решил, но нашел другое решение:

```
$ sudo touch ~/.config/autostart/chromium.desktop
$ sudo nano ~/.config/autostart/chromium.desktop
```

Добавить в файл строки:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Connect
Comment=Checks internet connectivity
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser -incognito --noerrdialogs --kiosk <url>
```

[Источник](https://devpractice.ru/raspberry-pi-autostart-chromium-in-kiosk-mode/)